# Finding a span with specific content using xpath

Tags: html, xml, xpath, selenium

I have some span's like this:

```
<span> 
  <span>foobar</span>  
  <span>thisisatest</span> 
</span>
```

I'm trying to use xpath to find the span with "thisisatest" in it.

I've tried this:

`span[text()='thisisatest']`

and it doesn't seem to be working.

Answer (score 35):

You are missing `//` at the beginning of the XPath.

- One slash would mean "a span that is a child of a root node".
- Two slashes mean "find me any span with that text".

`//span[text()='thisisatest']`

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
span[span= "thisisatest"]
```

All `<span>` elements that contain at least one `<span>` element child with the value thisisatest.

Hope it helps!

Comment: That's not "All `<span>` elements that ...", it's "All `<span>` elements *contained within the root node* that ...'.  Which doesn't change the result for the question, but isn't quiet right as the description.